# How to create a custom header starting with underscore

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I have a RESTful API provider who is insisting on using a POST call with a header _method set to DELETE as a workaround for their DELETE calls not working.

This is how I think the syntax should be:

```
response = RestClient.post("path/to/url", "{}",
            {
                    :content_type => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    :accept => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    :'_method' => "DELETE"
            } )
```

However the header is being morphed as shown below running with RESTCLIENT_LOG=stdout

```
RestClient.post "<snipped>", "{}", "-Method"=>"DELETE", "Accept"=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "Content-Length"=>"2", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

As can be seen _method becomes -Method. How can I have a customer header with a key named _method please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [rest-client has special treatment for Symbol keys](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/v1.7.2/lib/restclient/request.rb#L544) in the headers Hash, to convert e.g. `:content_type` into `"Content-Type"`, which is nice and convenient.

The solution to your problem is to use a String instead:

```
response = RestClient.post("path/to/url", "{}",
             :content_type => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
             :accept => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
             "_method" => "DELETE"
           )
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan - worked a treat after I noticed I left the : sign in - apologies ....

Comment: Are you sure? In your question you're still using a Symbol. `:"_method"` is a Symbol (it starts with `:`), whereas `"_method"` is a String.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a string instead of a symbol: `"_method" => "DELETE"`. RestClient will prettify (and convert to string) any symbol keys, but leave string keys as-is. [Source](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/4cc904f230a259f8293f3777a49e796e3a97d607/lib/restclient/request.rb#L560)